# How to avoid counting the non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: c

I am making a crypting program for CS50x and I have a small problem. I am trying to crypt some text using a vigenere cipher(cipher that uses a word as key). The problem I have is that, whenever I have a space or a non-alphabetic character, my  keeps incrementing. As per the spec, it shouldn't... Therefore, some characters are getting  using the wrong key... Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Here is a small part of my code to help you understand the problem.

```
for(int x=0, i = 0 , textlen = strlen(text); x < textlen; x++ , i++ ) 
    if (isalpha(text[x]))
    {

        if (islower(keyword[i % num_letters]))
        {
            if (islower(text[x]) && ((text[x] + (keyword[i % num_letters]) - 'a') <= 'z'))
            {
                text[x]= (text[x] + (keyword[i % num_letters]) - 'a' ); 
            }

            else if (islower(text[x]) && ((text[x] + (keyword[i % num_letters]) - 'a') > 'z' ))
            {
                text[x]= ('a'+ ((((text[x]) - 'a') + ((keyword[i % num_letters]) - 'a' )) % 26));

            }
        }
    printf("%c", text[x]);
    }
    else 

// Print the non-alpha char as they are 
    {
        printf("%c", text[x]);

    }
```

I hope this piece of code help you to understand. This is just a fragment from the code but it should be enough to understand the problem and perhaps suggest a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You can't instance variables inside for cycle `for (int i = 0;...`
2) The `% 26` seems to be the problem there, you should debug that ;)
3) I assume you're implementing your own crypto just for pleasure/didacting purposes, you should never ever ever ever ever ever (one more time) ever design your own crypto for real enviroments. Is really bad idea, your crypto could be broken really easy or don't work properly and cause lose of data (maybe really important data)

Comment: The `if (islower(text[x]) && ((text[x] + (keyword[i % num_letters]) - 'a') <= 'z'))` and next `else if()` appear wrong.

Comment: @Mr.E What's wrong with that variable declaration?

Comment: What does "my keeps incrementing" mean?

Comment: incrementing means that my i goes +1. I don't think there is a problem with the if, it encrypts the way it should except that it counts the punctuation and the space character. 
@Mr.E, can you be more precise about what you think the problem is with the modulo 26? I used modulo 26 to make sure I don't get a value that is not an alphabetic ASCII character.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a weird way to solve it, but I think a simple solution would be, in your else statement, decrement your i value. The problem is that regardless of whether you are entering the if/else statement, both will finish and return top, where you are incrementing it as if nothing changed. A more readable solution would be to take the control of your i variable away from the for loop itself and only increment i right before/after you print the char

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I used the «simple» way by decrementing i in my else statement. Good idea!